# Need help merging two macros for Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Both of these macros are macros I found online and adapted to my use.  I am using this code and it works well to separate specific data into new sheets:

```
        Sub Copy_To_Worksheets()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim ErrNum As Long

    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
    'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
    'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
    'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.


    Set My_Range = Range("A1:Z" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    My_Range.Parent.Select

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
    'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
    FieldNum = 5 'I changed this to 3 for column C

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Add a worksheet to copy the a unique list and add the CriteriaRange
    Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add

    With ws2
        'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
        My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

        'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
        Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & Lrow)

            'Filter the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
             Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

            'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                     .Areas(1).Cells.Count
            On Error GoTo 0
            If CCount = 0 Then
                MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                     & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                     & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                       vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
            Else
                'Add a new worksheet
                Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Name = cell.Value
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ErrNum = ErrNum + 1
                    WSNew.Name = "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000")
                    Err.Clear
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                'Copy the visible data to the new worksheet
                My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                With WSNew.Range("A1")
                    ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                    ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    .Select
                End With
            End If

            'Show all data in the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

        Next cell

        'Delete the ws2 sheet
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        On Error GoTo 0

    End With

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    If ErrNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
             & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
             & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
    End Sub
```

What I need help with is to add a particular set of formulas to the bottom of each sheet that is created from the above macro.  The following macro adds the formulas to all the sheets in the workbook.  I need it to add the formulas to only the sheets that are created in the above macro.  The number of sheets created change every time they are generated, depending on the source data.  I was thinking it might be best to merge bottom macro into the top but I have no idea how to go about doing that.

```
Sub Insert_Formulas()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate

    'Start
    NxtRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With Cells(NxtRw, "B")
     .Value = "Total Open Cases"
    End With

    With Cells(NxtRw, "C")
      .EntireRow.Insert
      .Value = "Total Closed Cases"
    End With

    'Next Row below
    NxtRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With Cells(NxtRw, "B")
     .Formula = "=CountIf(B2:B" & NxtRw - 1 & ", ""Open*"")"
    End With

    With Cells(NxtRw, "C")
     .Formula = "=CountIf(B2:B" & NxtRw - 1 & ", ""Closed*"")"
    End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,  Ck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you parametrize the function so that it takes the worksheet which needs the formulas as a parameter

```
Sub Insert_Formulas_Into_WorkSheet(ws As Worksheet)

    ws.Activate

    'Start
    NxtRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With Cells(NxtRw, "B")
     .Value = "Total Open Cases"
    End With

    With Cells(NxtRw, "C")
      .EntireRow.Insert
      .Value = "Total Closed Cases"
    End With

    'Next Row below
    NxtRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With Cells(NxtRw, "B")
     .Formula = "=CountIf(B2:B" & NxtRw - 1 & ", ""Open*"")"
    End With

    With Cells(NxtRw, "C")
     .Formula = "=CountIf(B2:B" & NxtRw - 1 & ", ""Closed*"")"
    End With
End Sub
```

Then you can add the formulas after each new worksheet is created by calling

```
 Insert_Formulas_Into_WorkSheet WSNew
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't combine the 2 macros, simply call the `Insert_Formulas` macro from the `Copy_To_Worksheets` macro when it is needed.

To call the macro all you need is this line:

```
Insert_Formulas
```

**Edit to respond to comment:**

Given you don't know how many sheets are being added I have one suggestion you may try.

High level, add text to a cell in each sheet to indicate if it is new or not. When new sheet is created cell should say "new". When not new it should say "existing". Then in the

If you want to give this a try, and let me know what doesn't work I can check back and help update the code.

1. In the `Copy_To_Worksheets` macro you'll need to add a line to set all existing sheets to "existing"
2. In then `Copy_To_Worksheets` macro add a line so that new sheets get set to "new"
3. In `Insert_Formulas` macro, still loop through all sheets, but check to see if the sheet is "new", and if so, run the code to add the formulas.

A cleaner (but slightly more difficult) option would be to define a name on each sheet (use the same name for each and limit the scope to each individual sheet) and use that instead of a cell on each sheet.

Comment: Thanks but I have several more sheets in the workbook I don't want the formulas added to.  I'm trying to find a way to add the formulas only to the newly created sheets.